# How to enable selection of entire Table item when TableEditor is used

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm using SWT table which consists of one column and i'm using SWT TableEditor to edit the column values.

When i try to edit a particular row, only the text of that particular TableItem gets selected.

Is there any way to enable the entire selection of that Table item.

My selectionListner code for the table looks like this:

```
final TableEditor editor1 = new TableEditor(table);
    //The editor must have the same size as the cell and must
    //not be any smaller than 50 pixels.
    editor1.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
    editor1.grabHorizontal = true;
    editor1.minimumWidth = 130;
    final int keyEditableColumn = 0;
    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
    {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
        {
            // Clean up any previous editor control
            Control oldEditor = editor1.getEditor();
            if (oldEditor != null) oldEditor.dispose();

            // Identify the selected row
            final TableItem item = (TableItem)e.item;

            if (item == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // The control that will be the editor must be a child of the Table
            Text newEditor = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);

            //Adding the list of Text Widgets that have been created for a component. 
            textWidgetsList.add(newEditor);

            newEditor.setText(item.getText(keyEditableColumn));
            newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
            {
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent me) 
                {
                .....
                .....
                .....
                .....
                .....
                                    }
            });
            newEditor.selectAll();
            newEditor.setFocus();
            editor1.setEditor(newEditor, item, keyEditableColumn);              
        }
    });
```

Please let me know your suggestions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your `Table` with the style `SWT.FULL_SELECTION`.

Comment: yes i did create the table with style as SWT.FULL_SELECTION. But still i end up with the same issue. Anything else i'm missing?

Comment: Then apparently I did not understand what exactly your problem is and what you are trying to achieve.